# Javascript reload page after popup submit Coldfusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a popup window where my user can edit information displayed on the parent page. When someone press submit changes on the popup window i need the popup to close and also the parent page to reload to display the new information.

I know there are a lot of examples out there but the questions displayed here did not provide me with enough information to complete my task.

I am currently using onClick="history.go(0)" which take me back to the parent page but does not reload the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the pop up window from within the pop up window use this:

```
self.close();
```

To RELOAD the window that opened the pop up use this in the pop up window:

```
window.opener.href = 'URL';
```

This should be pretty close to what you need.

Comment: i need to reload the parent not close it though.

Comment: I edited my answer. I know that you need to use "window.opener" and then the appropriate method.

Answer (score 2):

The question was a bit vague (not really a question at all, even), but you can try `window.location.href="/parentpage";`

Comment: let me know what you did not understand and I will rewrite it. thanks for the recommendation, I'll try it

Comment: I suppose that I need to replace the /parentpage with the correct url right?

Comment: yes, if you give the element an `id="foo"` then select it with `$('#foo').click(function() { /* do some stuff then... */ window.location.href="/path/to/parentPage"; });` was the idea i was going with.

Comment: that was the jquery way of selecting it. if you use an old onclick attribute (not very highly recommended for maintainability) then it might look something like `onclick="function() { window.location.href='/path/to/parentPage';return false; }"`